# I'm trying to add functionality to ensure that my program randomly selects an answer to respond to a student

Tags: java

Various comments that should be displayed for each answer are as follows:
Possible response to a correct answer:
Very Good!
Excellent!
Nice work!
Keep up the good work!
Possible responses to an incorrect answer should be:
No.Please try again
Wrong.Try once more.
Dont give up
No. Keep trying.

Im supposed to use a random-number generation to choose a number from 1 to 4 that will be used to select one of the four appropriate responses to each correct or incorrect answer. Im also supposed to use a switch statement to issue the responses.

```
package com.mycompany.multiplicationquiz;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Ayaan
 */
public class MultiplicationQuiz {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    generateRandomNumbers();
    
}

public static void generateRandomNumbers(){
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    int n1 = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
    int n2 = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
    
    generateQuestion(n1,n2);
    
}

public static void generateQuestion (int n1, int n2){
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.print("How much is " + n1 + " x " + n2 + " ?");
    
    int typedAnswer = sc.nextInt();
    

    
    if(typedAnswer == (n1*n2)) {
        System.out.println("Very good!");
        generateRandomNumbers();
    }else {
        System.out.println("No. Please try again.");
        generateQuestion(n1,n2);
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: what is your question/issue ?

Comment: Im supposed to use a random-number generation to choose a number from 1 to 4 that will be used to select one of the four appropriate responses to each correct or incorrect answer. Thats my issue I dont know where to start doing that

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Stack Overflow isn't the place to get your homework solved.

However, helping you manage to do it yourself is fine, so I'll attempt that here.

I see that you already used `SecureRandom` in your code, so I'd assume you were handed this way by your teacher.

Basically, what you want to do is to first check if the answer given is right.
Next, generate a random number using the code you already have.
Finally, create a `switch` statement that selects what answer to use based on the random number generated.

Comment: the switch is a bit overkill. Using an array and this random value as index would be easier

Comment: The OP specified `Im also supposed to use a switch statement to issue the responses.` in their question.